# Positive even numbered integer solutions of $y=n^2-m^2-x^2$

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Prove that no integer $x$ exists where $y=n^2-m^2-x^2$ has solutions:

- For all **even** integer values of $y$ in the range $2\le y \le 2x+1$ where $x$ is **odd**.
- For all **odd** integer values of $y$ in the range $1\le y \le 2x+1$ where $x$ is **even**.

Assume $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}$.

---

I've noticed that:

1. $x<n<\frac{x^2+2x+1}{4}$ and $\sqrt{n^2-(x+1)^2}<k<\sqrt{n^2-x^2}$
2. $x \rightarrow odd \Rightarrow (k \rightarrow even,n \rightarrow odd) ||(k \rightarrow odd,n \rightarrow even)$
3. $x \rightarrow even \Rightarrow (k \rightarrow even,n \rightarrow even) ||(k \rightarrow odd,n \rightarrow odd)$

Per @individ 's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351491/integral-solutions-of-hyperboloid-x2y2-z2-1/709219#709219), there is a set of solutions at:

#### $k=1\pm{b}$

#### $x=\frac{(b^2+y\pm{2b})}{2}$

#### $n=\frac{(b^2+2+y\pm{2b})}{2}$

But this doesn't seem to represent all solutions for any given $y$.
The statement can also be expressed
[as related right triangles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJnWj.png)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803972/which-integers-can-be-written-as-x22y2-3z2/2804058#2804058

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351491/integral-solutions-of-hyperboloid-x2y2-z2-1/709219#709219

Comment: That's helpful @individ. How did you derive the particular solutions in the integral solutions problem? And will they produce all possible solutions for $X$, $Y$, and $Z$?

Comment: you can rewrite the equation as: $y + x^2 = n^2-m^2 = (n-m)(n+m)$. So you are looking for numbers that can be represented as $N=y+x^2$. For example, $6+3^2=15=4^2-1^2$

Comment: you change the upper limit on x from $2x+1$ to $2x$ with even y. The solution I gave in my previous comment is still valid for $y=6$ and $x=3$.

Comment: For odd y, we also have solutions:  $5+4^2=21=5^2-2^2$ with $y=5, x=4$

Comment: @user25406 fixed upper limit. You can actually use the inequalities from point 1 above to generate valid values for $y$ for a given $x$ by sweeping $n$ and subsequent valid values of $k$ to get them.

Comment: I don't understand why you start with "Prove that no integer $x$ exists where $y=n^2−m^2−x^2$ has solutions" when we can easily find solutions for both odd and even y.

Comment: Looking for a proof that no integer $x$ exists with solutions for **all** even or odd values of $y$ over that range, not just a few. Rewrote to make that slightly clearer.